# Is it possible to activate specific version of process builder(or flow) through API?

Tags: process-builder, deployment, visual-workflow, metadata-api

[image]

For the situation shown in the above picture, is it possible to activate a specific version of process builder(or flow) through API?

Comment: in API version 43 and earlier it was possible to use FlowDefinition object in order to retrieve all flow versions. Back then Flow object contained active flow definition property, so it was possible to activate any available flow version using metadata api

Comment: What is the condition which determines which version of the flow you would like to use?

Comment: @Cleverlemming I didn't enable "deploy flows as Active" feature when I deployed flows to production and that caused older version of flows to be active but the newer version should be. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can try looking  at retrieving and deploying with the metadata api but I dont't think this will fix the versioning issue. Deactivating the currently active vesion and then cloning the version you want to be active might be easier.